# Returning to US avoiding arrest warrants

Tags: usa, dual-nationality

I have dual citizenship of US and another country. I have a felony warrants/bench warrants in US.

I wish to return to the US, is it possible to return there avoiding arrest by using different country passport with different name?

Comment: Not a risk worth taking.

Comment: You are still the same person, with the same fingerprints and facial structure.

Comment: We're not too keen on helping users break the law.

Answer (score 6):

> If you are a U.S. citizen you must, by law, enter and depart the United States on a valid U.S. passport, regardless of age or possession of foreign passports.

(Source: [U.S. Embassy in Australia website](https://au.usembassy.gov/u-s-citizen-services/citizenship-services/dual-nationality/))

So no, you cannot use your other passport to enter US.

Also, just for you to know, what you are trying to do sounds illegal and may get you in even more trouble.

Comment: You really think he cares if it's illegal? He's running from a felony arrest warrant which is "more illegal."

Comment: I know he probably doesn't care, just wanted to mark that by doing it he could get in even more trouble.

Comment: Not to be rude, but the OP seems quite naive in regards to his belief that travelling on a different passport could outsmart immigration officers and/or the State Dept, FBI. I know a relative of my father who got pulled off a connecting flight from Aus to Canada via Hawaii for simply overstaying on his Nigerian passport several years back in the US despite having gained australian citizenship and travelled on a different passport.